# How do I remove the line breaks around my <input> element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML...

```
<label for="addnewlocationpostcode">Postcode: </label>
<input type="text" id="addnewlocationpostcode" placeholder="Enter postcode" />
<button id="addnewlocationpostcodecheck" type="button" class="btn btn-primary inline"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

When this is displayed in the browser, all three elements are on separate lines. I want them all on one line.

Using Chrome's inspector, I can see that the margin of the `input` element seems to be full width, even though Chrome claims the margin is zero...

[image]

My (uneducated) guess is that if the margin is full width, the element has to be its own line.

However, if I type `$("#addnewlocationpostcode").css("margin")` into the console, it gives an output of `"0px"` which sounds like jQuery thinks the margin is zero.

I don't have any CSS set on any of these elements. The only CSS that is used on the page is the standard Bootstrap .css file that I downloaded from their site. Even if I had some custom CSS set, I still don't understand how Chrome shows the margin as being the full width of the container when I select the element, but jQuery reports it as zero.

I tried setting the margin manually using `$("#addnewlocationpostcode").css("margin-right", "10px")` and the like, but it didn't make any difference what value I used, it always looked the same.

Anyone able to explain what's going on? More to the point, how do I fix it so that all three elements are on one line?

Comment: Post your CSS. Are you using Bootstrap? The HTML you posted *does* all render on a single line, so there must be CSS rules causing this.

Comment: When i use code on jsfiddle with and without bootstrap all is in one line.
Paste the css code too.

Comment: They are likely block level elements. Try targeting them and changing them to inline-block.

Comment: @j08691 As I said in my original post (edited to make it clearer), I haven't set any CSS on these elements. I only have the standard Bootstrap .css file included. I don't have any other CSS to add to the post.

Comment: So then why, when I paste your code into a Bootstrap page, does it render fine? https://www.bootply.com/PO8OVOE6jb

Comment: @j08691 I have no idea, what's why I posted the question. I have used very similar markup plenty of times before and not had this problem. As I haven't set any CSS on the elements, I couldn't see why it was breaking. I was hoping someone else could suggest something I hadn't tried. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link where we can see this happening? The code above isn't enough to reproduce your issue. Does this happen in all browsers? Clear your cache? Disable any plugins/addons/extensions?

Comment: @j08691 It was a plug-in. Please see my answer below. It looks like the plug-in's Javascript is emitting some CSS that causes the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be caused by [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com), which I'm using on the page. It's not the CSS for the plug-in, but something in the Javacript, as when I commented that out, the elements displayed correctly.

Which doesn't really help me much, as I can't control what CSS the plug-in emits. Looks like I might need to rethink either using that plug-in or the way I display these elements.

Answer (score 0):

As said j08691, it seems that you are using bootstrap, then try to put the `form-inline` class to your `<form>` element.

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" id="addnewlocationpostcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter postcode" />
  <button id="addnewlocationpostcodecheck" type="button" class="btn btn-primary inline"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0c0mfnp/

Every details are here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

I hope it helped you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that and it didn't make any difference. My elements weren't actually in a `form`, but I tried adding one to see if it helped.